# How do I take the mean of this output

Tags: python, list, statistics

I have this function

updated the code a bit

```
for c,d,y in zip(crypto.Wicker,crypto.Dateroundts,crypto.Dateround1ts):
        yst = cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(c,'usd', d, y)
        print(c)
        #yst = {k: [[np.nan, np.nan]] if not v else v for k, v in yst.items() }
        bst = list(yst.values())[0]
        caz = []
        for new_lst in bst:
            caz.append(new_lst[1])
            print(caz)

buu-inu
[1.7844348972932573e-05]
[1.7844348972932573e-05, 1.8661555226871793e-05]
[1.7844348972932573e-05, 1.8661555226871793e-05, 1.879232323095649e-05]
[1.7844348972932573e-05, 1.8661555226871793e-05, 1.879232323095649e-05, 1.8801994944205594e-05]
```

What I want is to take all the prices for the individual coin and take the mean. Then put said mean into the list. If I do something like `mean(new_lst[1])` I'll get an error float object is not iterable

heres what `print(bst)` outputs

```
buu-inu
[[1637557978123, 1.7844348972932573e-05], [1637559018888, 1.8661555226871793e-05], [1637560001812, 1.879232323095649e-05], [1637560315539, 1.8801994944205594e-05]]
```

The first number is the time in unix and the second input is the price

Comment: `mean(new_lst)` ?

Comment: so ``bst`` has two outputs, the time in unix and the price. That's why there's an ``new_lst[1]``

Comment: `mean(b[1] for b in new_lst)` ?  Or `mean(list(zip(*new_lst))[1])`.

Comment: As the comments are saying, you need to isolate this data as a list. Make sure that, if it is a dictionary, you are getting the correct column, making sure that it is a list if need be using `list()` then ideally you should be able to use your `mean` function.

Comment: @Samwise both of those gave an int' object is not subscriptable
error oddly

Comment: @LarrytheLlama the problem is that if I put it in a list in the for loop then it's just gonna turn each individual output into a list and if I put it outside the for loop then it'll put the entire thing into a list. I basically need a list for each coin so I can take the mean of that.

Comment: Is `new_lst` even a list of all the same type of thing, or is it a mishmash?  The comprehension you use to build `yst` looks like it could easily be mangling the format of the data.  Maybe you could turn this into an MRE by providing a sample return value of `get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id`.

Comment: @Samwise Here let me make a couple edits to give a bit more insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this value of `bst`:

```
>>> bst = [[1637557978123, 1.7844348972932573e-05], [1637559018888, 1.8661555226871793e-05], [1637560001812, 1.879232323095649e-05], [1637560315539, 1.8801994944205594e-05]]
```

you can unpack each sublist into time and price and take the mean of the prices:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean(price for [_, price] in bst)
1.8525055593741612e-05
```